# If $n$ divides a product, what else does it divide?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We have that $n$ divides the product $ab$.

Then does n divides also?

- $gcd(a, b)$
- $lcm(a, b)$
- $gcd(n, a)\cdot b$
- $a-b $
- $gcd(n, a)\cdot gcd(n, b) $

Since $n$ is not necessarily a prime we cannot be sure if it divides one of the first two, right?

I think that n divides the last one, because these are factors of the factorization of n.

Is that correct?

Comment: Hva you tried small examples already?

Comment: Let n=6 and a=2 and b=18. Then gcd(a, b) =2, gcd(n, a) =2, gcd(n, b) =6, lcm(a,b)=18. For these n divides the second, third and 5th expression tgat we have above. Right? @DietrichBurde

Comment: Only the last one is interesting. And also clear, when considering prime divisors of $n$. Because then $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Comment: So you meanto take as n a prime number? @DietrichBurde

Comment: No, I mean to consider all prime divisors of $n$.

Comment: In this case we have 2 and 3 @DietrichBurde

Comment: How does that help us? I got stuck right now. @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 2):

Write $n=\prod_ip_i^{n_i}$ etc. so $n_i\le a_i+b_i$. As @DietrichBurde notes, only the last problem warrants attention. The claim to assess is $n_i\le\min\{n_i,\,a_i\}+\min\{n_i,\,b_i\}$. This holds if $a_i,\,b_i\ge n$ so the RHS is $a_i+b_i$; otherwise, without loss of generality $n_i<a_i\implies n_i<a_i+\min\{n_i,\,b_i\}$.